# Limit Windows fiewall inbound rule to IIS only

Tags: firewall, iis

I have created a new website on IIS which I want to access via my public IP.

However to do this I needed to update Windows firewall by adding a new inbound rule.

I've set up the ports (80),and protocols(TCP).

So far so good. Everything works.
However I want to restrict the inbound rule to IIS.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything else listening on port 80, so it's probably sufficient to filter just to that port, but defense in depth is good.

Using the advanced firewall tool (`wf.msc`), edit your inbound-TCP-80 rule. Go to the "Programs and Services" tab and click `Settings` in the Services box. Only apply the rule to the IIS service that needs access to port 80 (or 443, if you're supporting HTTPS).

I believe this service is `W3SVC`, the "World Wide Web Publishing Service". I'm not certain though; just going off these pages: http://blogs.iis.net/tomwoolums/the-services-behind-internet-information-services-7-0 and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734944(v=ws.10).aspx.

You can also restrict the rule to the service binary (probably `svchost.exe`, which is used for a lot of stuff, but better than nothing).